# CE 1.9.1.1 - Determine which user created backend order

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, reports, user-roles, ce-1.9.1.1

we have created a **Telesales** role inside Magento with relevant permissions, and have assigned users (Telesales agents) against that role.

Now I am aware of the SO post [Differentiating Backend vs. Frontend Purchases in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570909/differentiating-backend-vs-frontend-purchases-in-magento), but I need to find a way to show orders created by a specific backend user. Is this possible? I have also looked into the Advanced Reports extension from AheadWorks, but this doesn't seem to be a feature they support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to find the admin orders created by a specific user

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
       ->addFieldToFilter('remote_ip',array('null' => true)) // this will load all admin orders
       ->addFieldToFilter('customer_firstname',array('eq' => 'Joe')); // here you can also use customer_id/customer_email/customer_lastname..
echo "<pre>";print_r($order->getData());
```

Comment: Thanks Manashvi. Wouldn't this still be looking at orders for a particular **customer** instead of a backend user?

Comment: There is no way to filter the order collection by admin user in particular

Comment: @ManashviBirla https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/286442/57334 Any help thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Manashvi mentioned, there is no way to understand which *specific user* created an order. However, we have made use of IWD's Sales Rep Tracking extension which has fulfilled this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new module that created a foreign key in the order to the admin user table and records the logged-in admin user who places the order.

But that didn't help for older orders. So I also did this that implements a `Grid` that selects from the `sales/order` table instead of the `sales/order_grid` table.

Note: This is just an example. Collection code should go in the collection class.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

    $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('IF(ISNULL(remote_ip), 0, 1)');

    $collection->addExpressionToSelect('is_web_order', $expr);
    $collection->addFilterToMap('is_web_order', $expr);
}
```

Then in `Grid.php`:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('is_web_order', [
        'header'            => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website') . ' ' . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Order'),
        'index'             => 'is_web_order',
        'type'              => 'options',
        'width'             => '50px',
        'options'           => [
            0   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No'),
            1   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes'),
        ],
        'filter_index'      => 'is_web_order',
        'sortable'          => false,
        'align'             => 'center',
    ]);
}
```