# Magento 1.9 - Multi-Website Sales Order View Restrict based Admin-User

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website, admin-user, website-restriction

I am running Multi-website.

I have two stores for my two vendors both of my vendors are my admin users, `[system->permission->users]`. If `vendor-1` login to admin panel they also able to view `vendor-2` store and vice versa.

> How can I restrict Admin-User by website?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: I have two stores for my two vendors both of my vendors are my admin users, [system->permission->users] if vendor 1 login admin panel they also view vendor2 store also, and vice versa